# How to run java 11 compiled program with jre 8 classes in JVM 11

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, java-11

[java 8 landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1PE8.jpg)  [java 11 landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSmiP.jpg)I have an application which uses java print library ( javax.print.* and java.awt.print.* ) for printing data in printer pages. The application was developed in java 2 and is working fine till java 8. But since my application is upgraded to use java 11. I am facing issues when printing data in printer in Landscape Orientation. Means the issue is, the data printed in paper will be moved a bit upwards around 3mm from the original position. As I haven't done any code changes in my application , I feel some jre classes might have changed or some changes in jvm 11 might be...

So, I thought to run this java 11 program with jre 8 classes in JVM 11. Can anyone let me know how to do... Or where should I debug so that I can come to know which jre classes have changed which is causing this issue.

To check the issue , you can download the zip from http://www.netcat.li/download.html  , inside that will contain reportcat_limited jar and also the examples. I took SimpleTableExample.java .

Anyone's help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: looks like debugging would be the way to go, may be that "3 mm" was an issue until java-11 - that was actually fixed.

Comment: No one can tell you where to debug without code.

Comment: I am sorry to say, its client code. Cant share... One more thing is we use reportcat library which uses java print library for printing http://www.netcat.li/java-report-printing-library/ 

the display of data is fine in portrait mode. but landscape has issue...

Comment: You may consider writing a small, self standing, complete example which you CAN share showing this behavior.  This either documents a bug or helps you locate the problem in your code (might be something very simple).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have posted the pics reproducable steps at the end of the summary. Thanks!

Comment: The sample code needs to be short enough to include in the question. You need to do further investigation as to what reproduces the problem.